# How to restore activity state from onPause(onSavedInstanceState won't help)

Tags: android

basically my app has 2 activities.Say "A" and "B" . A launches B.

Activity B plays music(in a service) and also has a notification.

when the view is on activity B and i press back button ,and then i click on the the notification, activity B is opened with the state of activity completely lost and music also stops(not desired)......i am making a guess that it happens because when i press the back button the activity is  explicitly destroyed ,so i have to progamatically restore its view right??

## first thing that comes into mind is using onSavedInstanceState

but that won't help because onSavedInstanceState is not called when user presses back button (i read it in the docs) so what are my alternatives??

Comment: @Raghunandan my problem is not yet solved...

Comment: hmmm onSaveInstanstState is best used for maintaing flags very small data for UI, For your music stuff try to play music from a background service and not UI

Comment: @PulkitSethi that is what i m doing but for the simplicity of question i didn't mention it here.......

Comment: @PulkitSethi by the way don't u sleep?its almost 4... :)

Comment: @user2993677 good luck to solve your problem. You say Activity B plays music and also has a notification. So whereis the service used. I don't understand.

Comment: override onBackPressed (), and save data to some persistence storage like temp preferences, should be quick enough for small data

Comment: @Raghunandan activity B doesn't play music,it launches a service to play music......i thought there was no need to mention it i was not having problems with the service......the real question is related to saving and restoring service,doesn't matter what activity is doing what.....so have i made myself clear to you now??

Comment: @Raghunandan stop wasting other people's time by asking useless details when you know you can't answer the question....

Comment: @user2993677 fine don't post good luck. you have not understood my previous comments and you say i can't answer your question. No problem. Find and answer yourself or wait till some one gives your perfect and proper answer.

Comment: @Raghunandan the real question is not at allrelated to which activity is doing what..and you didn't understand the comment i posted before

Comment: @user2993677 fine. i don't understand and i can't give you an answer. So don't bother to comment further. Good luck in solving your problem.

Comment: thank you but i already got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to save data in `onPause()` and restore it in `onResume()`. Next question is where to store data. The are few way to do that:

1. **Using custom application context**

You can extend `android.app.Application` and register your class in your manifest file by

```
<application android:name="your.application.class" ...
```

This will allow you to get singleton instance of your class by calling `Context.getApplicationContext().

For an example you can create

```
public class MyContext extends Application {
Bundle mySavedData = null;

public void setSavedData(Bundle data){
    mySavedData = data;
}

public Bundle getSavedData() {
    return mySavedData;
}
}
```

and then use it like this

```
@overide
public void onResume(){
    ...
    Bundle state = ((MyContext) getApplicationContext()).getSavedData();
    if(state != null) {
        /* restore states */
    }
    ...
}

@overide
public void onPause(){
    ...
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    ...
    /* save your data here and save it into the context or set null otherwise*/
    ((MyContext) getApplicationContext()).setSavedData(state);
    ...
}
```

1. **Using singleton pattern**

Instead of defining context you can create singleton instance

```
public class MySingleton {
    static MySingleton instance;

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new MySingleton();
        } 
        return instance;
    }

    public Bundle mySavedData = null;
    void setSavedData(Bundle data){
        mySavedData = data;
    }

    public Bundle getSavedData() {
        return mySavedData;
    }
}
```

and you can use it

```
@overide
public void onResume(){
    ...
    Bundle state = MySingleton.getInstance().getSavedData();
    if(state != null) {
        /* restore states */
    }
    ...
}

@overide
public void onPause(){
    ...
    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    ...
    /* save your data here and save it into the context or set null otherwise*/
    MySingleton.getInstance().setSavedData(state);
    ...
}
```

Be aware that context and singletons are destroyed if application is killed. If you want to store your data permanently than using application document folder or database if recommend but I think that isn't what you looking for.

I hope this will help you....

Comment: thank you...i will use your answer tomorrow and will let you know if it helps,because its 3 at night here....i think i will be reading and researching on it right now...

Comment: i was thinking if i should call the destroy method on pressing the back button??so that onDestroy is called and hence OnSavedInstances is called and this will reduce the amount of work i will have to do...do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: Take a look on [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Application may be killed before `onDestroy()` is called, but at that point context and singleton are lost... So, I think that will probably do a job... You can use `onDestroy()`\ `onCreate()` combination.

Comment: i didn't get you.... will i be able to use savedinstances( i somehow find using saved instances very easy that is the reason i want to use it..)

but i think it won't help because if i explicitly destroy the activity then ondestroy wont be called and hence onsavedinstancestate wont be called as well,i dunno why think there should be an easier way of restoring the activity state after pressing back button...

Comment: Yes, u can use them, but system will not store bundle for you, because you are starting fresh instance of activity. You must store `Bundle` by yourself, and for that I recommend using singleton. If you do not use saved instances, u can store your data in preferences just like @user2993972 said...

Comment: can you please explain the registration part?in xml??do we need to register contexts in manifest??

Comment: and by android:name="your.application.class" ...
do u mean 
android:name="MyContext.class"
in this case?

Comment: my app crashes  upon playing music.....

Comment: by android:name="your.application.class" I mean android:name="com.mydomain.myappname.maypackage.MyContext"

Comment: do i have to declare it in the manifest if i am using the option 2??i.e Singleton class???... my app is crashing after using singleton ...(i didn't declare it iin the manifest..)

Comment: Second way is easier and you don't need to declare it inside manifest. Singletons are created after `getInstacne()` first call....

Comment: but my app is crashing when i use your code....

Comment: ???????????...................

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you with that. Something else is causing the problem. Use LogCat to find out what....

Comment: well i haven't got your code working but atleast now i know where to begin nd thanx to u

Comment: i still haven't understood how to declare in the manifest..... the manifest already has application tag in it..should i create a new one or should i add another tag in it?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote onSavedInstanceState won't help because your activity is destroyed and recreated. If you need to save the state of activity in the app lifecycle, you will need to store the data externally- for example in data base. For small data you can use shared preference.

Comment: i am not sure that this is what the music player apps generally do when we press back button...

Comment: i was thinking if i should call the destroy method on pressing the back button??so that onDestroy is called and hence OnSavedInstances is called and this will reduce the amount of work i will have to do...do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: It won't help you because when you will return to the activity the onCreate() will call with null savedInstanceState. This is because the activity destroyed...

Comment: i don't think so...if that is the case then what is the use of savedinstances ??

Comment: maybe u r right...because in this case again i m explicitly calling the destruction of the activity

Comment: Its more because when you are clicking the notification you open a fresh instance of activity B- its not recreated.

Comment: no i have tried to change the settings in the manifest to single instance ...then too the UI vanishes and musicstops..that means activity is being recreated(i guess)